# QGraphicsView error - Trying to show a jpg with Python

Tags: python, qgraphicsview, qt-designer

I'm using Python 3.2 with Eric5 and QTDesigner to try and display a jpg in a QGraphicsView scene.  The following code gives me a 
**The file could not be opened.  Reason: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "**
error on the first pass and then ends with a 
**The debugged program raised the exception unhandled AttributeError
"'MyForm' object has no attribute 'QGraphicsView'"
File: , Line: 17**

The referenced screentest.ui file is just a simple QGraphicsView object box on a form.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
 #UIGraphicTest.py

import sys
# from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from screentest import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myapp = MyForm()
  grview = myapp.QGraphicsView()
  scene = myapp.QGraphicsScene()
  scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('att-logo.jpg'))
  grview.setScene(scene)

  myapp.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you post your generated `.py` GUI file? You should have given the `QGraphicsView` a name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to move my scene up to the class and then reference the name of the QGraphicsView object.  I also added the ctypes for use in Windows. Here's the working code:

```
#UIGraphicTest.py

import sys,  ctypes
#from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from screentest import Ui_MainWindow

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    #Prevent grouping with python in Windows
    myappid = 'UIGraphicTest'
    ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
    # Create a Scene
    self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('logo.jpg')) 
    self.ui.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myform = MyForm()
  myform.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```